# Extend or override blanks theme js

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, overrides, extend

I have a custom theme which inherits from blank and I would like to override navigation-menu.js options how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can override navigation-menu.js into your theme and you can changes as per your requirement.

path for override js,

> app/design/fronntend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/js/navigation-menu.js.

After override you have to just deploy command to see changes on frontend.

Remove `pub/static/frontend` folder and deploy below command.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Remove var folder.
Check again.

Comment: I made the proposed but now I'm not sure about if is the right js which is responsoble for top navigations behavior. I do not see under network as loaded